# React & Typescript - Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Very new to React Hooks and can't get past Invalid Hook Call.

```
    export default function ResultsPage({ x, y }: ResultsPageProps): ReactElement {
       const [order, setOrder] = useState('ascending');

       return (
         <>
           ...
         <>
       );
```

I've read the docs, but I'm lost on why this doesn't work.

```
 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476:13)
    at useState (react.development.js:1507:20)
    at Module.ResultsPage (ResultsPage.tsx:92:66)
    at _callee$ (main.tsx:40:67)
    at tryCatch (regeneratorRuntime.js:44:17)
    at Generator.eval (regeneratorRuntime.js:125:22)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (regeneratorRuntime.js:69:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:7:24)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:26:9)
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Read rules of hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html